# getimagesize() failed to open stream: Too many open files

Tags: php

Запускаю скрипт на локальной машине, он открывает изображение, делает ресайз и сохраняет.

Код открытия:

```
$imageInfo = getimagesize ($filePath);
$this->_width = $imageInfo[0];
$this->_height = $imageInfo[1];
$type = Helper::mime2ext ($imageInfo['mime']);
$this->_extension = $type;
switch ($type) {
    case 'gif' :
       $this->_image = imagecreatefromgif ($filePath);
       break;
       case 'jpg' :
          $this->_image = imagecreatefromjpeg ($filePath);
          break;
       case 'png' :
          $this->_image = imagecreatefrompng ($filePath);
          break;
        }
$this->_size = filesize ($filePath);
unset($imageInfo);
return true;
```

Код сохранения:

```
if (!imagejpeg ($this->_image, $path, $quality))
        return false;
imagedestroy($this->_image);
unset($this->_image);
return true;
```

Не могу понять откуда эта ошибка
`Warning! getimagesize("path/to/image.jpg") failed to open stream: Too many open files`

UPD. Скрипт выполняется циклом 250-290 раз и вылетает эта ошибка,  операционная система MacOS

Comment: Какая операционная система у вас на локальной машине?

Comment: На локальной машине стоит MacOs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Надо увеличить возможное число открытых файлов. Если в MacOS это нельзя сделать, то придется отказаться от getimagesize и посчитать вручную.
Вот есть либа - https://github.com/marc1706/fast-image-size